# Hide subprocess output and store it in a variable in Python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pyffmpeg

I would like to call a FFmpeg command, which produces a very big output.

I need to store the output in order to make a regex on it.

On the first command (echo), nothing is printed in my terminal, but for the ffmpeg command, huge output is produced (which I want to store in a variable, I don't want to have the output in my terminal)

So my code looks like this for example:

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output("echo a lot of wooooords")
output = subprocess.check_output("ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -f null -", shell=True)
```

Is it possible to hide the output for this command? Why does it show me an output? Thank you

Comment: The output may be to stderr. Try adding `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` as a parameter. That will send both stdout and stderr to stdout.

Comment: s/may be/is quite certainly/

Comment: BTW, `shell=True` is a bad idea here, _especially_ if the `audio.mp3` file name isn't hardcoded. Consider using `['ffmpeg', '-i', 'audio.mp3', '-f', 'null', '-']` with the default `shell=False` so you can replace `audio.mp3` with a variable without incurring security bugs.

Comment: you can pass `-loglevel quiet` to FFmpeg